# Regarding Focus in Customised Button added to vfm

Tags: blackberry, customization, imagebutton, vertical-alignment, horizontalfieldmanager

I have created a class which has 10 customised Buttons which are added to VFM .. 
But when i go from 1st button to another its disappears and when i go on the last button it reappears

When i am on the 1st button and press two times the Up button from keyboard it disappears and then again reappears when i change to 2nd button ??
What's the problem with it

and vice versa happpened to the last button 
when i added the button to the HFM

The code which i use is in this link 
http://pastebin.com/1Y9siJcj

Comment: Most probably it's the problem with your Customised Button, provide us with the code for your custom button.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1Y9siJcj is the code for CustomButton which i use

Comment: Your code is working well on my side, I'm using it as, `VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 vfm.add(new CustomButtonField(bmNormal, bmFocused, Field.FOCUSABLE));
}
add(vfm);`

Comment: @Rupak: i found out that it works fine for 9 buttons 

But as soon as i add the 10th buttons the buttons began to disappear

Comment: I have modified the code a little here, http://pastebin.com/JYrRfbbQ. You can check that. May be implementation of onFocus() or onUnfocus() causing problem.

Comment: I have said earlier that your code is working on my side, and you don't post any code about how are you using that button. And now I have added a trimmed version of your CustomButtonField in answer section with an application. Check that.

Comment: layout image, http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1zcpxxj&s=5, source code http://pastebin.com/Lcf2Aw2k, http://pastebin.com/TEYgAsgv. I have voted for deleting the answer below  (posted by me) and checking your layout and code.

Comment: @Yak, I have modified implementation of VerticalFieldManager. Now it only uses 3 fields but you can add more to them. If you check the code you will see how the manager layouts its childs. Code here, http://pastebin.com/9RR4XQnD